# How to change UITextField RightView size?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I trying put to 2 items in rightView component. for example;`

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -80, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100))
    label.text =  String(self.availableBalance) + " ₺"
    label.textColor = Colors.INVEST_RED
    label.textAlignment = .center
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: -100, y: 15, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "full_balance_button")
    rightView.addSubview(imageView)
    rightView.addSubview(label)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(tapGesture)) 
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    rightView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    rightView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true     
    rightView.backgroundColor = .white
    textField.rightView = rightView
    textField.rightViewMode = .always
```

But I can't change size rightView.

Comment: try to give width constraint to rightView.

Comment: I tried told but never changes at rightView size